# can't run rspec test Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rspec-rails

I'm trying to run a test from root directory but I just get errors.

[Terminal screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iPljG.png)

Instead if I run the test form the spec folder I don't get any errors but it doesn't see my test file:

Finished in 0.00058 seconds (files took 0.14195 seconds to load)
0 examples, 0 failures

Any idea what could be the issue?

Comment: From your stack trace, it looks like there's an error trying to create an instance of one of your Active Record models. Are you creating an ActiveRecord object that has a description property in one of your before blocks in your test?

Comment: It seems that I didn't close the before block before running the test, I really didn't see it.  Thank you.